# Using Thinkpad X131e charger on Ideapad S10e

Tags: laptop, power-supply, lenovo-laptop

Can I use my Thinkpad X131e charger on my Ideapad S10e? They have different ends. I figured that instead of buying a new charger, it would be cheaper to buy a converter. The voltage of my charger is the same (20v) and has a higher amperage. The polarity is also the same. I have done a bit of googling and found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004L6WW46). It looks like the charger will fit, but I am not sure if the male plug will fit in the S10e netbook. Will this work?
If not, is there one that will fit or can I possibly make one myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to re-using of chargers across devices - the critical things are

1. Voltage - Ensure that the voltage levels are the same - as the
   battery charger circuit inside the devices expects nearly the same
   voltage in DC.
2. Current - the mA rating of the charger should match or be higher
       than that is required.

I think as far as the physical connection (converter) goes - it is a passive device and matching the plug and socket is the only criteria (And clearly the members cannot say if it will match or not). Ensure that the converter doesn't reverse the polarity internally (i doubt if they would build converters like that). You can test this using a simple multimeter.